# Bootstrap Card Header: pull-right

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

How should i get my small text right aligned in a Bootstrap 4, Card Header?

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="card">
        <!--CARD HEADER-->
        <h4 class="card-header">HEADER <small class="pull-right">right aligned</small></h4>
        <!--CARD BODY-->
        <div class="card-body">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

This is what i have tried:
https://jsfiddle.net/LL0qnnxm/60/

Comment: have you tried giving `small` tag a `float:right;` ?

Comment: @OvidiuUnguru no. But it did work =)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use `float-{sm,md,lg,xl}-right` instead of `pull-right` because it changed in Bootstrap 4. For more info please read this https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/migration/

And for your solution please check the updated [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LL0qnnxm/61/)